# WCF, Exceptions & Inheritance

Tags: wcf, exception

More than halfway through the web-service project I am currently working at, my customer decided to inform me just now that I can't ever throw exceptions to client applications. The question is that until now I was throwing `FaultException` exceptions everytime there was a validation, database or any other kind of error. I will clearly need to change this behavior without further questions, but the problem is that I don't really know what to replace it for. The service has 4-5 endpoints which return different `DataContract` structures, so I thought about designing a base class having a boolean (indicating failure or success) and `object` (which I would use to send the serialized exceptions if they are to be thrown) fields and make all the other `DataContracts` inherit from this structure. But I am not really sure this is the best option. What do you advise me to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requirement is probably due to the fact that Silverlight consumers are supposed to access the service which can't handle those exceptions in a proper way unless they switch to the http client stack (which comes with its own drawbacks).

We've solved the problem by including a Fault out parameter in every service method signature that needs to be checked by the client. It really sounds worse than it is in practice.

Comment: It is a good idea which may work well in my case, but in fact it doesn't sound like being too elegant...

Comment: Here's an article about the topic http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/01/27/returning-exception-information-to-a-silverlight-client-through-wcf.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Well, I think I will have to really use this approach. I had never thought about it... It may not be too elegant but if the customer wanted something elegant this requirement would not have been posed anyway... So, off to work changing every signature!

Answer (score 1):

This will work for sure for service operations that return something. So if you only have that kind of operations use it like you proposed: try catch in the service operation and wrap the exception in the returned data contract.

What about the service operations that have a void return type? You could also try catch but how do you return the status/error to the client? Are you gonna hev this scenario in your app?